# Data does not load when reloading the page, but when I click elsewhere and clink back to the component then the data fetches in datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working with MDBDataTable for react and having trouble loading the data after reloading the page. But when I go to another component and visit back the TopSearchSelect component then the data gets loaded to the datatable.

[Data does not load when refreshing the page][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MArri.png
[Data gets loaded when going to another component and then back][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZxu6.png

**TopSearchSelect.js**

The getClients() is working and getting saved to redux store.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { MDBDataTableV5 } from 'mdbreact';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { getClients } from '../../actions/clients';


const TopSearchSelect = ({ clients, getClients }) => {

const [datatable, setDatatable] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getClients();
    setDatatable({
        columns: [
            {
                label: 'First Name',
                field: 'firstName',
                width: 150,
                attributes: {
                    'aria-controls': 'DataTable',
                    'aria-label': 'Name',
                },
            },
            {
                label: 'Last Name',
                field: 'lastName',
                width: 270,
            },
            {
                label: 'Phone',
                field: 'phone',
                width: 200,
            },
            {
                label: 'Email',
                field: 'email',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 100,
            },
            {
                label: 'Date added',
                field: 'date',
                sort: 'disabled',
                width: 150,
            },

        ],
        rows: clients && clients.map(client => ({
            firstName: client.firstName,
            lastName: client.lastName,
            phone: client.phone,
            email: client.email,
            date: client.date,

        })) || []
    });

}, []);


return (

     <MDBDataTableV5
        hover
        entriesOptions={[5, 10, 20, 25]}
        entries={5}
        pagesAmount={4}
        data={datatable}
        pagingTop
        searchTop
        searchBottom={false}
     />

   );
  }

TopSearchSelect.propTypes = {
 getClients: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  clients: state.clients.clients
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getClients })(TopSearchSelect);
```

**Clients.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import TopSearchSelect from '../layout/TopSearchSelect';

const Clients = () => {

  return (
    <Fragment>
        <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Clients</h1>
        <TopSearchSelect />
    </Fragment>

   )
 }

export default Clients;
```